# (Haskell) How to convert from Ratio Integer to Ratio Rational?

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

How does addition of two different ratios work? For instance, ratio integer and ratio rationals don't seem to get added. I tried evaluating the continued fraction for a given list.

Here's the code :

```
import Data.Ratio
f :: [Integer] -> Rational
f(x:xs)
  | (null xs == True) = x
  | otherwise       = x + (1 % f xs)
```

What is the correct version of the code supposed to be? Since f yields a Ratio Rational, I feel that x, if type-casted to a Ratio rational number, will suffice.

Comment: I do not think that is sufficient, since `(%)` has type `(%) :: Integral a => a -> a -> Ratio a`, it thus can not take a `Ratio Integer` as second parameter.

Comment: Alright. Is Rational and Ratio Integer the same thing?

Comment: yes, `type Rational = Ratio Integer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No type conversion needed, use proper division between rationals.

```
import Data.Ratio

f :: [Integer] -> Rational
f []           = error "empty list"
f [x]          = x % 1
f (x:xs@(_:_)) = x % 1 + 1 / f xs
```

Here, `x % 1` makes `x` into a `Rational` (ok, that's conversion, if you want). We could also have used `fromInteger`, I think.

Then, between `Rational` values, we do not use `%` which produces a weird `Ratio Rational`, but we exploit `/` which produces a `Rational` instead.

Comment: I see, makes so sense now. Could you also tell me why "(((toRational 1)%1) % f xs)" is treated as Rational while "1 % f xs" is treated as Ratio Rational? I believe that the second is treated so because f yields rationals and so the (%) coupled, gives you the Ratio Rational. How did the first one become a pure Rational?

Comment: As Willem Van Onsem commented before, the type has to be Integral, which isn't the case here apparently.

Comment: Additionally, I could have just changed the (%) in the last statement of my post to (/) and write the x as "x%1" (or "toRational x") in all places. Thank you nonetheless!

Comment: @charles: note the difference between `(%)` and `(/)`.

Comment: @charlesh Not sure about why that is a `Rational`. It doesn't look as such to me. (?)

Answer (score 2):

Converting `x` to a `Rational` will not be sufficient here. Since you here write `1 % f xs`. The type of `(%)` is [**`(%) :: Integral a => a -> a -> Ratio a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html#v:-37-), and since `f xs` is a `Rational`, and `Rational` is not an instance of `Integral`, we thus need to fix a second issue.

It is however not that hard. We can for example make a function that calculates the inverse:

```
inverseR :: Integral a => Ratio a -> Ratio a
inverseR r = denominator r % numerator r
```

Since `Ratio a` is an instance of `Num` given `a` is an instance of `Integral`, we can use [**`fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html#v:fromInteger):

```
f :: [Integer] -> Rational
f [x] = fromInteger x
f (x:xs) = fromInteger x + inverseR (f xs)
```

For example:

```
Prelude Data.Ratio> f [1,4,2,5]
60 % 49
```

Since 1 + 1/(4 + 1/(2 + 1/5)) = 1 + 1/(4 + 1/(11/5)) = 1 + 1/(4 + 5/11) = 1 + 1/(49/11) = 1 + 11/49 = 60 / 49.

We can further improve this by:

1. using [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert any integral to a `Ratio`; and
2. by using [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-).

We thus can generalize this to a function:

```
f :: (Integral a, Fractional b) => [a] -> b
f [x] = fromIntegral x
f (x:xs) = fromIntegral x + 1 / f xs
```

Which yields the same value:

```
Prelude Data.Ratio> f [1,4,2,5] :: Rational
60 % 49
```

We can use a `foldr` pattern, and avoid the explicit recursion:

```
f :: (Integral a, Fractional b) => [a] -> b
f = foldr1 (\x -> (x +) . (1 /)) . map fromIntegral
```